# In R, how to remove the indices of steps from the plot of the path of two random walks?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the path of 2 random walks (Xt, Yt) in R.

```
X(t+1) = X(t) + Z(t+1), X(0) = 0,
Y(t+1) = Y(t) + W(t+1), Y(0) = 0,
```

Z(t) and W(t) are i.i.d. standard normal N(0,1).
So I write the following R code:

```
set.seed(100)
r1 <- c(0, rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1))
r2 <- c(0, rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1))
x.ts <- as.ts(cumsum(r1))
y.ts <- as.ts(cumsum(r2))
plot(x.ts, y.ts)
```

The graph I get has indices on each point like this:
[figure1: line path with numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Ml2.jpg)

How can I remove the numbers from line to get this:
[figure2: without number indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYJs3.jpg)

I get figure 2 by the following code:

```
x.vector <- as.numeric(x.ts)
y.vector <- as.numeric(y.ts)
plot(x.vector, y.vector, type="l")
```

What parameters can I add in

```
plot(x.ts, y.ts, ...)
```

to have the same output? Many thanks!

Comment: Use `xy.labels = FALSE`. You can see this option at the `?plot.ts` help page.

Comment: A solution using the tidyverse: library(ggplot2); library(tibble)
as_tibble(x.ts, y.ts) |>
  ggplot(aes(x.ts, y.ts)) +
  geom_path()